# Error in retrieving public dns name of ec2 instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to retrieve public dns name of an ec2 instance.

Here is my python3 script.

```
import sys
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

instance_id = "i-03e7f6391a0f523ee"
action = 'ON'

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')


if action == 'ON':
    # Do a dryrun first to verify permissions
    try:
        ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=True)
    except ClientError as e:
        if 'DryRunOperation' not in str(e):
            raise

    # Dry run succeeded, run start_instances without dryrun
    try:
        response = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
        print(response)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
else:
    # Do a dryrun first to verify permissions
    try:
        ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=True)
    except ClientError as e:
        if 'DryRunOperation' not in str(e):
            raise

    # Dry run succeeded, call stop_instances without dryrun
    try:
        response = ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
        print(response)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)

instance = ec2.Instance('i-1234567890123456')
while instance.state['Name'] not in ('running', 'stopped'):
        sleep(5)
        print("the instance is initializing")

#pubdns=instance.PublicDnsName

#print ("public dns name"+pubdns)
def get_name(inst):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds = [inst[0].instance_id])
    foo = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Association']['PublicDnsName']
    return foo


foo = get_name(instance_id)
print (foo)
```

If I use

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
```

in the above code, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'Instance'

and if I use

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
```

then I get this error instead:

> AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'start_instances'

what I want to do is to be able to connect to an ec2 instance and retrieve its publicdns name.

I have changed the code now based on below suggestions

```
import sys
import boto3


instance_id = "i-03e7f6391a0f523ee"
action = 'ON'

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
#instance = ec2.resource('ec2').instance(instance_id)
if action == 'ON':
   response = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
else:
    response = ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
print(response)



def get_name(inst):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds = [inst[0].instance_id])
    foo = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Association']['PublicDnsName']
    return foo


foo = get_name(instance_id)
print (foo)
```

but now I get error

```
in get_name
    response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds = [inst[0].instance_id])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'instance_id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating two ideas in one.

boto3.client creates an object through which you look up resources like ec2.

Once you have a resource, you can begin to manipulate it.

Use

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
```

and then

```
instance = ec2.resource('ec2').instance(instance_id)
```

The second looks up your ec2 instance from the ec2 *resource*, not the boto3 ec2 client.

Comment: I am not clear with difference between boto3.client and ec2.resurce()

Comment: I get the error again 
`instance = ec2.resource('ec2').instance(instance_id)
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 555, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'resource'`

Comment: I have changed the code and mentioned new in in question still there is error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code in case any one hits here in future I am posting it.This will print public DNS name of all of your instances after switching them on and then shutdown them.

```
  import boto3
from pprint import pprint


ec2=boto3.client('ec2')
response=ec2.describe_instances()
print (response)

instancelist = []
for reservation in (response["Reservations"]):
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        instancelist.append(instance["InstanceId"])
print (instancelist)


action ='ON'
if action == 'ON':
   response = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instancelist, DryRun=False)

ec2client = boto3.resource('ec2')
#response = ec2client.describe_instances()


instances = ec2client.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running','stopped']}])
ids = []

for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)
    ids.append(instance.id)
    resp=ec2.describe_network_interfaces();
    print ("printing pub dns name")
    print(resp['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Association']['PublicDnsName'])


ec2client.instances.filter(InstanceIds=ids).stop()
```